# Convert xml to dictionary error

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Similar questions have been asked before, but I cannot find the answer to the problem I have.

I want to use linq xml functions to convert my config.xml settings into dictionary, but always got `Possible System.NullReferenceException`. So, I need to check whether the attribute and its values exist.

What's the syntax to do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <Services>
    <add key ="key1"   value ="value1"></add>
    <add key ="key2"   value ="value2"></add>
    <add key ="key3"   value ="value3"></add>
 </Services>
</configuration>
```

my lambda code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(configFilePath);
var d = (from name in doc.Descendants("Services") select name)
         .ToDictionary(n =>  n.Attribute("key")
         .Value, n.Attribute("value")
         .Value);
```

Comment: I tried to use another approach, but got the similar error: doc.Descendants("Services").ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("key").Value,
                                                     x => x.Attribute("value").Value
                    );

Comment: That's the exact same approach.  Syntax looks different, but it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Descendants("add")` instead of `Descendants("Services")`

```
var dict = XDocument.Load(configFilePath)
        .Descendants("add")
        .ToDictionary(n => n.Attribute("key").Value, n=> n.Attribute("value").Value);
```

---

```
var dict = XDocument.Load(configFilePath)
       .Descendants("Services").First()
       .Descendants("add")
       .ToDictionary(n => n.Attribute("key").Value, n=> n.Attribute("value").Value);
```

Comment: you are correct. Another ways is find the "Services" element first, then first its descendants. At document level, it will find "Services" element only. How to catch exception if "services" node has no such attributes?

Comment: @ericyoung `Services` has no attributes, it has elements.

Comment: Understood. Just want to know: how do you catch exceptions in lambda expression? should I use a try/catch outside of it? such as try { var dict =  ....} catch (exception e) {} ?

Comment: Trying to catch exceptions in lambda would make your code seem very ugly. injecting some `Where`s to check null cases would be better.

Comment: I accidently used two same keys in the config file, and got "same key has been added to the dictionary" exception. Should I used a try/catch outside of the lambda expression?